# How to convert a grayscale image to heatmap image with Python OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a `(540, 960, 1)` shaped image with values ranging from `[0..255]` which is black and white. I need to convert it to a "heatmap" representation. As an example, pixels with `255` should be of most heat and pixels with `0` should be with least heat. Others in-between. I also need to return the heat maps as Numpy arrays so I can later merge them to a video. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here are two methods, one using Matplotlib and one using only OpenCV

**Method #1:** `OpenCV` + [`matplotlib.pyplot.get_cmap`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.get_cmap)

To implement a grayscale (1-channel) `->` heatmap (3-channel) conversion, we first load in the image as grayscale. By default, OpenCV reads in an image as 3-channel, 8-bit BGR.
We can directly load in an image as grayscale using [`cv2.imread()`](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) with the `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` parameter or use [`cv2.cvtColor()`](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html) to convert a BGR image to grayscale with the `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` parameter. Once we load in the image, we throw this grayscale image into Matplotlib to obtain our heatmap image. Matplotlib returns a RGB format so we must convert back to Numpy format and switch to BGR colorspace for use with OpenCV. Here's a example using a scientific infrared camera image as input with the `inferno` colormap. See [choosing color maps in Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) for available built-in colormaps depending on your desired use case.

Input image:

[image]

Output heatmap image:

[image]

Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('frame.png', 0)
colormap = plt.get_cmap('inferno')
heatmap = (colormap(image) * 2**16).astype(np.uint16)[:,:,:3]
heatmap = cv2.cvtColor(heatmap, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('heatmap', heatmap)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Method #2:** [`cv2.applyColorMap()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html)

We can use OpenCV's built in heatmap function. Here's the result using the `cv2.COLORMAP_HOT` heatmap

[image]

Code

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('frame.png', 0)
heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(image, cv2.COLORMAP_HOT)

cv2.imshow('heatmap', heatmap)
cv2.waitKey()
```

---

**Note:** Although OpenCV's built-in implementation is short and quick, I recommend using Method #1 since there is a larger colormap selection. Matplotlib has [hundreds of various colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#choosing-colormaps-in-matplotlib) and allows you to [create your own custom color maps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html) while OpenCV only has 12 to choose from. Here's the built in OpenCV colormap selection:

[image]

Comment: OpenCV allows you to use custom colormaps too, it's just not as easy or straight forward as using the built-in ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the image to a proper grayscale representation. This can be done a few ways, particularly with `imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`. This reduces the shape of the image to `(54,960)` (hint, no third dimension).

Comment: So how to convert it to an heat map?

Comment: The 2D array is itself a heatmap. Think of it as I(u,v) is the "heat" (intensity) at coordinates (u,v).