# How Does Tensorflow.keras's ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory scale image values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras, tf.keras

I have a trained tensorflow model and while making the training database, I used

```py
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(organized_dir,
                                       target_size=(image_dim, image_dim),
                                       color_mode="grayscale",
                                       batch_size=20,
                                       shuffle=True,
                                       follow_links=True)
```

(I'm just showing the parameters I chose to supply, the variables such as `image_dim` are defined elsewhere)

When I look at one of the batches using `next()` on the DirectoryIterator object that the function returns, the pixel values of the image seem to be scaled from their original rgb values [0,255] to grayscale [0,1]. I want it as grayscale, and my understanding is that ML models perform best with numbers between 0 and 1. So that's great!

However, now I want to use the model on different images. Opening them in `cv2`, and converting to grayscale does not scale the pixel values in the same way that tensorflow does it, it just keeps the color values in [0,255] instead of [0,1]:

```py
>>> z = cv2.imread("img.png")
>>> cv2.cvtColor(z, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
array([[255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       ...,
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

So, what I'am asking is how do I use the same conversion that tensorflow's dataset uses to make an image use pixel values from [0,255] to [0,1]. I found here that I could normalize the images: [Normalizing images in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025838/normalizing-images-in-opencv/3804199). But I would like to use the exact algorithm/parameters that tensorflow uses so I can maximize my real world accuracy. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrect about the ImageDataGenerator rescaling the images pixel values. According to the documentation the generator has a parameter called rescale. For this parameter the documentation states:

```
rescale: rescaling factor. Defaults to None. If None or 0, no rescaling is applied,
 otherwise we multiply the data by the value provided
 (after applying all other transformations).
```

so to rescale the values from 0 to 1 then use

```
rescale=1/255
```

Many models used in transfer learning require the pixel values to be between -1 and +1.
For that case use

```
rescale=1/127.5-1
```

It may be that the images you were reading in already had their pixel values rescaled. To test if your image is pre-scaled use

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
path_to_file=        #specify the full path to the file
img=cv2.imread(path_to_file,0)# read in image as grayscale
max_pixel_value=np.max(img) #  find maximum pixel value
min_pixel_value=np.min(img) # find minimum pixel value
print('max pixel value= ', max_pixel_value, '  min pixel value= ', min_pixel_value)
```

Comment: This makes sense, but why would the cv2 `imread()` give pixel values between 0 and 255?

Comment: Also, is there a way to check whether the pixel values were already rescaled?

Comment: see updated answer. I have verified the generator does NOT rescale the pixel values unless you specify the value of the rescale parameter.

Comment: @Vladimir Kulyashov seems to be right that cv2 reads them as `dtype=uint8`, although you have the right answer for what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

cv2.imread() reads images as np.array with data type uint8. That's why you have all the values from 0 to 255. To rescale values to [0, 1] just divide them by 255

```
In[1]: import cv2
  ...: import numpy as np
In[2]: img = cv2.imread('some_image.jpg')
In[3]: img
Out[3]: 
array([[[110,  89,  92],
        [110,  89,  92],
        [ 50,  29,  32],
        ...

In[4]: type(img)
Out[4]: numpy.ndarray

In[5]: img.dtype
Out[5]: dtype('uint8')

In[6]: img = (img / 255)
In[7]: np.min(img), np.max(img)
Out[7]: (0.0, 1.0)

In[8]: img
Out[8]: 
array([[[0.43137255, 0.34901961, 0.36078431],
        [0.43137255, 0.34901961, 0.36078431],
        [0.19607843, 0.11372549, 0.1254902 ],
        ...

In[9]: img.dtype
Out[9]: dtype('float64')
```

Here is a quote from docstring of ImageDataGenerator:

> rescale: rescaling factor. Defaults to None.
> If None or 0, no rescaling is applied,
> otherwise we multiply the data by the value provided
> (after applying all other transformations)

So the answer for your question: just multiply your array by 1/255 and you'll get the same result as ImageDataGenerator returns