# Normalization does not do anything

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

When I use the command

```
img2 = cv2.normalize(img, np.zeros((150, 150)), 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

I get the exact same image as "img".

Why is it happening? Is it suppose to be like that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normalizing images in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025838/normalizing-images-in-opencv)

Comment: Did you pass a 3-channel image `img` as input? If so, you are likely to receive the same as the output. You are expected to pass a single channel as input. Try passing `img[:,:,1]`.

Comment: please present a [mre]. your post lacks a concrete `img`